# Javascript - Object iter from Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm learning Javascript and today I learned AJAX.
I am using Vanilla JS and simple AJAX.
My task is to get the object of a user from the url by user input - ID.
I've tried the .data and still won't work.
Any help would be appriciated!

```js
async function display() {
  try {
    let id = +userID.value;
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const rootObject = await response.json();
    const users = rootObject.data;
    getUser(users);
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);
  }
}

display()
```

I have another function - getusers(users) that currently is empty because it isn't working.
How can I access the object only from the url?

Comment: There is no data property in the (parsed) JSON returned. `console.log(rootObject)` to see the actual structure of the object. `response.data` is something you normally see with Axios which isn't what you're using.

Comment: When I write console.log(rootObject) I get the user by ID. But when I want to display it with getUser function it won't display it

Comment: We don't know how your `getUser` function works

Answer (score 1):

There is no `data` property in the returned JSON. Just parse the JSON and then have that data as an argument to `getUser`.

```js
function getUser(data) {
  for (const prop in data) {
    console.log(`${prop}: ${data[prop]}`);
  }
}

async function display(id) {
  try {
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    getUser(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}

display(3);
```